# How to do split select like ui bootstrap slipt dropdown

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to split normal selectbox which should look like default ui bootstrap dropdown. I have used uibootstrap dropdown, but problem is selected dropdown value will not be displayed on top as like normal dropdown do.

Please let me know how do i split the select.?

Comment: plunker,jsfiddle... please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the current selected item as button label with the ui bootstrap split button like this:

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group dropdown" uib-dropdown="" style="">
  <button id="split-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{selectedItem || 'Choose Item'}}</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="split-button" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectItem(item)"><a href>{{item}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.items = ['action 1','action 2','action 3'];

$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
  $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

See this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZoMoa2t3JZDNiZ3eQoW?p=preview